# Flexible array member in class with polymorphism

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, flexible-array-member

In C99 you can have something like

```cpp
struct foo
{
    int a;
    int data[];
};
```

And then allocate with `foo* f=(foo*)malloc(sizeof(foo)+n)` to have a struct where the length of the array is `n`.

Can one do something similar in C++ when the class is a subclass with virtual functions?

Like `foo` being a subclass of bar, then do something like `std::unique_ptr<bar> f= std::unique_ptr<foo>((foo*)malloc(sizeof(foo)+n))`

I know that that code doesn't work as freeing the memory would be done with `delete` but allocation was done with `malloc`

Comment: Using raw dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` or operator `new`) is considered poor practice in C++.  Consider using a standard container, such as `std::vector<int>` which will give you a dynamically allocated and - with care - a resizeable set of `int`s  (since it does dynamic memory allocation behind the scenes, rather than you doing it directly).   If you really must use `malloc()` to allocate memory, you can use `std::unique_ptr<>` but provide an (optional) deleter that uses `free()`.   `malloc()` is not compatible with classes in C++, except in special circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible by standard rules. Variable-length arrays and  flexible array members, such as you show in your example, are not allowed in C++ at all. There is no equivalent or alternative either.

Also, `malloc` cannot be used to create objects in C++ at all. Only `new` with the correct type given to it can create an object of that type dynamically. Everything else is not allowed and causes undefined behavior if one pretends that an object of the given type was created.

Since C++20 there are some exceptions to the rule above for certain types of objects which may be created implicitly, but still, the size of an object is fixed at compile-time by its type and can not be varied at all.

Overallocating for an object does never cause the additional storage to become part of the object and one is never allowed to access it as if it was.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays are not actually part of the C++ standard, but rather a compiler extension. However, if you really want to use them, I mean, allocating the object with `malloc`, you would need to use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to call the constructor, and manually call the destructor (which should be virtual) like `f->~bar()` before calling `free`. Since `malloc` produces a pointer to memory of necessary size for initialization of the object, this shouldn't produce undefined behaviour.